# Configuring ASA: I can browse out, but no incoming traffic?

Tags: cisco-asa, firewall, nat, ping

I can't seem to get this code working. I'm not well versed in ASA setups, but there seems to be an increase in popularity around here for them, and word gets out that if you can work on one, you're their guy and the guy for all their friends. Needless today, I copied a configuration from one ASA and modified it to match the settings needed for another location of the business.  I was able to get out to the internet, however, when the other agency tried to ping some equipment at the location so they could do their job, the equipment could not be pinged. I'm not sure how much more specific information you need, but any assistance on this would be more than wonderful.

```
CISCOASA(config-if)# show run
: Saved
:
ASA Version 8.2(5)
!
hostname CISCOASA
enable password encrypted
passwd encrypted
names
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.#.#.33 255.255.255.240
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 70.#.#.78 255.255.255.224
!
ftp mode passive
clock timezone CST -6
clock summer-time CDT recurring
object-group network StateNet
 network-object 10.#.#.0 255.255.254.0
 network-object 10.#.#.192 255.255.255.240
 network-object 170.#.#.32 255.255.255.224
 network-object 170.#.#.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.#.#.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.#.#.210 255.255.255.255
object-group network Inside
 network-object 10.#.#.32 255.#.#.240
access-list outside_cryptomap extended permit ip object-group Inside object-group StateNet
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip object-group Inside object-group StateNet
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging asdm informational
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 0 access-list inside_nat0_outbound
nat (inside) 1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 70.#.#.78 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
http server enable
http 10.#.#.32 255.255.255.240 inside
http 170.#.#.100 255.255.255.255 outside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
crypto map outside_map 1 match address outside_cryptomap
crypto map outside_map 1 set peer 170.#.#.5
crypto map outside_map 1 set transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA
crypto map outside_map 1 set nat-t-disable
crypto map outside_map interface outside
crypto isakmp enable outside
crypto isakmp policy 1
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
telnet timeout 5
ssh timeout 5
console timeout 0

threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
webvpn

tunnel-group 170.#.#.5 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 170.#.#.5 ipsec-attributes
 pre-shared-key *****
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map
  inspect ftp
  inspect h323 h225
  inspect h323 ras
  inspect rsh
  inspect rtsp
  inspect esmtp
  inspect sqlnet
  inspect skinny
  inspect sunrpc
  inspect xdmcp
  inspect sip
  inspect netbios
  inspect tftp
  inspect ip-options
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context
no call-home reporting anonymous

: end
CISCOASA(config-if)#
```

Comment: I guess what's bothering me the most about this is that I copied a working sh run from a primary site to mirror those settings to the secondary site, of course with the appropriate changes to the IPs, and it's not working. I can get out, but people can't get in.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a network diagram, including subnets and vlans that need to traverse the tunnel. Change any public IPs or private details.

Comment: @legioxi, here's what I have:

Your ACL for interesting traffic should mirror: 
access-list ### permit ip 10.#.#.0 255.255.254.0 10.#.#.32 255.255.255.248
access-list ### permit ip 10.#.#.0 255.255.255.0 10.#.#.32 255.255.255.248
access-list ### permit ip 10.#.#.192 255.255.255.240 10.#.#.32 255.255.255.248
access-list ### permit ip 10.#.#.210 255.255.255.255 10.#.#.32 255.255.255.248
access-list ### permit ip 170.#.#.32 255.255.255.224 10.#.#.32 255.255.255.248
access-list ### permit ip 170.#.#.0 255.255.255.0 10.#.#.32 255.255.255.248
My peer is 170.#.#.5

Comment: I do notice right away that there may be a difference in my subnet for the inside interface. My paperwork shows 3x255.240 when I think it should be .248.  Would that make a difference?  As far as a network diagram, These computers connect to an agency server and should be a site to site vpn.  I'm sorry I can't be of more help. I'm well versed in many things and haven't felt like a noob in a lonnng time. :)

Comment: @APA, I could really use some insight here. I've run a little shy on time and wouldn't mind being pointed in the right direction. I hope it to be something relatively simple to say the network is 1/2 way working. One Million Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the version of code on the ASA you copied from and on the ASA you copied to?  There could be a difference in the way the codes works if they are different that could be impacting the operation.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally we need more information...

1. What were they trying to ping and not able to reach? Is this interesting traffic related to the IPSec crypto?
2. What did you use to confirm internet reachability? Ping from the firewall via one of its interfaces or a machine behind the firewall?

However looking briefly at your config I noticed the following:

```
access-list outside_cryptomap extended permit ip object-group 
  Inside object-group SUPERS
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip object-group 
  Inside object-group SUPERS
```

The `SUPERS` object-group doesn't appear to exist in your configuration thus these two configuration lines won't actually be doing anything.

Also it doesn't appear like you're no natting the IPSec VPN traffic. To ensure when it crosses your outbound interface it isn't natted but rather kept with it's original source IP so it can traverse the IPSec VPN tunnel unmodified.

Comment: From the other side of this network, they should be able to ping an onsite printer to confirm its setup on a static IP. When they try to ping the printer, they cannot see it, therefore cannot confirm its setup.  However, the machines that I set up on the onsite network can browse out to the web, and also ping each other and the printer.

As far as the "no natting," I'll need a little help with that part.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have no access-lists applied.  Access-lists are applied to an interface using the `access-group` command, which I did not find in your configuration.

Without an access-list, traffic trying to pass through your ASA is filtered purely based upon your security levels.  Which means traffic from a higher security level interface is allowed to pass to a lower security level interface, but not the other way around.

Currently, you have two interfaces:

- Inside - Security Level 100
- Outside - Security Level 0

Any traffic that starts on the Inside (100) will be permitted to pass to the Outside (0).  But any traffic that starts on the Outside (0), will **not** be permitted to pass to the Inside (100).  The only way to override this behavior is to apply an access-list.

Note that since the ASA is a stateful device, the return traffic of a connection initiated from the Inside will still be allowed back through, even though the return traffic is coming from the Outside heading to the Inside.  Any traffic initiated from the Outside, however, will not be allowed through.

FYI, the access-lists is **definitively** preventing traffic from the outside from accessing the inside.  But I can't say for sure whether it is **solely responsible** for it.  There might be something else going on, but either way the lack of an ACL is your first issue to fix.

---

edit: You never mentioned if the "other agency" is coming from the Public Internet or from the other side of the VPN tunnel you have configured.  I answered with the assumption that they were coming from the Public Internet.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons you can't ping is that your ASA configuration lacks ICMP and ICMP ERROR inspect.

Modify your configuration to include the following commands:

```
policy-map global-policy
    class-map inspection default
        inspect icmp
        inspect icmp-error
```